# I Do Not Know Why One of These Two Plots Requires the /. Replacement Operator

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

Why does the first Plot require the '/.' replacement operator, but the second Plot does not? Both use InterpolatingFunctions.

In the first block of code, 'sol' is an InterpolatingFunction.  In the second block of code, iFun is an InterpolatingFunction.

I'm still new to Mathematica.

```
ode1 = {y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == 2, y'[0] == 1};
sol = NDSolve[ode1, y, {x, -10, 10}]
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, -10, 10}]
```

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1} {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
ifun = Interpolation[points]
Plot[ifun[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

I've tried various syntactic choices without success. I believe I am missing some key conceptual piece of information about how these features work.

Thank you.

Comment: To be precise, you know this, the first block returns a `Rule` `y->InterpolatingFunction[...]`, not just an `InterpolatingFunction`, and the second block returns `InterpolatingFunction[...]`. As you understand  `y/.y->InterpolatingFunction[..]` turns a `Rule` into an `InterpolatingFunction`. Now at a deeper level, why is it this way? Perhaps because for more complicated uses we want to manipulate or use that result in ways that might be less convenient if it returned just an `InterpolatingFunction` instead of a `Rule` Why they don't both return a `Rule`? Maybe the same, more convenient usually